# Java: problem with reading a file

Tags: java, file

I'm loading an XML file with this method:

```
public static String readTextFile(String fullPathFilename) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(1024);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullPathFilename));

        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while(reader.read(chars) > -1){
            sb.append(String.valueOf(chars));   
        }

        reader.close();

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

But it doesn't load the whole data. Instead of 25634 characters, it loads 10 less (25624). Why is that?

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BufferedReader` you get the readLine()-Method, which works well for me.

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( 1024 );
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fullPathFilename ) );

        while( true ) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line == null) {
                break;
            }
            sb.append( line );
        }
        reader.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* there's a bug in your code, the last read might not necessarily fill the char[], but you still load the string with all of it. To account for this you need to do something like:

```
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is));
    char[] c = new char[1024];
    while(true) {
        int charCount = r.read(c);
        if (charCount == -1) {
            break; 
        }
        res.append(c, 0, charCount);
    }
    r.close();
```

Also, how do you know you're expecting 25634 chars?

(and use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer, the former is not threadsafe so sightly faster)

Comment: What `is` is in your code? I know the lenght of the XML, I checked it and it's 25634 characters long. Also, I checked the last few characters from the string and I saw that there are only few characters missing at the end (I guess 10 :)).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have 25634 **Bytes** in your file that represent only 25624 **Characters**? This might happen with multibyte character sets like UTF-8. All `InputStreamReader` (including `FileReader`) automatically do this conversion using a `Charset` (either an explicitly given one, or the default encoding that depends on the platform).

Comment: I know the lenght of the XML, I checked it and it's 25634 characters (!) long.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileInputStream to avoid certain characters getting recognized as utf-8:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(1024);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
char[] chars = new char[1024];
while(reader.read(chars) > -1){
    sb.append(String.valueOf(chars));   
}
fis.close();

return sb.toString();
```